# Show that row operations leave column space of transpose unchanged?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, gaussian-elimination, transpose

Show that $col(A^T) = col(C^T)$, where $C$ is the matrix resulting from any number of row operations on $A$. I was given the hint that $A^T = C^T (P^{−1})^T$, but I don't see how I can conclude anything from that.

Comment: Do you have the result that the row space is preserved by row operations?

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't talked about the row space in lecture yet. I think I need to use the hint given to show equality.